# How is transparent background removed from a TIFF file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have a situation where I need to convert TIFF files to JPEG files in Python.  I am using the PIL library to do this and it works fine unless the TIFF has a transparent background on it and then PIL can't open the file and says it is not recognized.  Are there other solutions to this in Python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please take this [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64143055/edit) this post to include your own effort into solving the problem,[Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you please upload a sample **TIFF** image that you want to convert?

Answer (score 0):

TIFF format files usually consist of multiple images of different resolutions. Try reading with openslide

Eg:

```
patch = openslide.OpenSlide(img_path)
patch = patch.read_region((17800,19500), 0, (256, 256))
```

For more info visit openslide documentation

Comment: Hi @SudhirKumarSuman!  Thanks for the suggestion.  Do I need to install OpenSlide?  If so, how?